# aws eb cli set Healthcheck utl

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a `Django` app with `python 3.6` to `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`.  Does anyone know how to set the Healthcheck URL when creating or restoring an `elastic beanstalk` environment?  I have tried saving a configuration but that didn't store my custom URL so I downloaded it with eb config get, added it to the configuration manually (which I came across on an `aws` page)

```
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:
    Application Healthcheck URL: /accounts/login/
```

and did an eb config put.  Then I created an environment using the eb `create --cfg good_cfg`but that didn't restore the URL.  I have also set it via the web interface, terminated the environment and then restored the environment via eb restore env_id but the Healthcheck URL is set back to the default of /.

Here is my full 2020-01-12-test.cfg.yml file.

```
EnvironmentConfigurationMetadata:
  DateCreated: '1578859126000'
  DateModified: '1578859126000'
Platform:
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.4
OptionSettings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    BatchSize: '30'
    BatchSizeType: Percentage
  aws:elb:policies:
    ConnectionDrainingEnabled: true
  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    CrossZone: true
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    ServiceRole: arn:aws:iam::598520317272:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
    LoadBalancerType: application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:
    Application Healthcheck URL: /accounts/login/
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system:
    SystemType: enhanced
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
    SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:598520317272:certificate/4f82f8a4-cc06-48de-a96a-31bb6767f847
    DefaultProcess: default
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Rules: ''
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    EC2KeyName: aws-eb-coincounter
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Health
    RollingUpdateEnabled: true
EnvironmentTier:
  Type: Standard
  Name: WebServer
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
```

Comment: What type of application are you running? Health check is only available for load-balanced environments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "what type of application".  It is a Django app with python 3.6 running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  Health Check is certainly running as the app turns red if I don't change the URL in EC2 -> Targets Groups -> Health checks.  I just have to do this via the UI and would like a way to do it when the configuration launches.

Comment: Ah, ok, then you have a load balanced application. There's also an option for the EB application to be a single instance, which is quite common for test and prototype enviornments and there you can't do a health check.

Comment: Saving the configuration should also save the health check setup, it does for my project for sure.

Can you share your full launch config in the question? I can compare and maybe see something that can help.

Comment: I just edited my original post to include the contents of my configuration file.  I have a working environment and I just saved this configuration from it.  I then terminated the working environment and attempted to create a new environment using this configuration via aws web interface.  But when I loaded this environment it didn't even launch a load balancer and my SSL certificate was not configured even though it appears to be listed in this config file.  Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how these configuration files are to be used.

Comment: So since that environment didn't configure a load balancer or my SSL cert, I deleted it and then restored my original working environment.  And guess what?  The Health Check URL was switched back to / so I had to go in to EC2 -> Target Groups and edit it to be /accounts/login/.  And now my environment Health Check has changed back to green.  I would really like to figure out how to restore 100% of my manual configuration changes so that I can restore the environment without having to manually tweek it after it is created.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few settings for some reason. Here's what I think could help. Make sure to put in your SSL CERTIFICATE-ARN, there's just a placeholder in the example. There's also autoscaling based on latency, you might wanna change that to what you prefer.

```
AWSEBAutoScalingGroup.aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    MinInstancesInService: '1'
    RollingUpdateType: Health
    MaxBatchSize: '1'
    RollingUpdateEnabled: true
AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow.aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    LowerThreshold: '0.8'
    MeasureName: Latency
    Unit: Seconds
AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh.aws:autoscaling:trigger:
   UpperThreshold: '1.2'
AWSEBLoadBalancer.aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:<CERTIFICATE-ARN>
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
AWSEBLoadBalancer.aws:elb:policies:
    ConnectionDrainingEnabled: true
AWSEBAutoScalingGroup.aws:autoscaling:asg:
    MinSize: '1'
    MaxSize: '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see there are quite a few pieces of the configuration file that I am missing.  As I mentioned I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of the configuration file.  How exactly should I save my current configuration?  I am in ELB and click on my application environment.  There is an Actions button at the far right that has as an option "Save Configuration".  I just saved a new version of the configuration and it is exactly what I posted above.  Your code doesn't exist in my configuration.  How should I be saving my configuration? Or do I need to code it by hand?

Comment: You're doing everything correct. I'd suggest one more thing - switch to a 'classic' load balancer. You're using an 'application' load balancer which does not use a health check url, but defines a range of response codes that define health. It doesn't explain the disappearing configuration, but might help set up the health check.

More on the different types here: https://www.sumologic.com/insight/aws-elastic-load-balancers-classic-vs-application/